# Show that $\sum{\frac{x^n}{(1+x^n)^n}}$ converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Show that $$\sum{\frac{x^n}{(1+x^n)^n}}$$ converges uniformly on $[0,1].$

I am sorry but for this exercise I got exactly nothing. It seems to be difficult.

Comment: So far two deleted erroneous solutions. Yes, it's subtle. The Weierstrass M-test fails, as the maximum of the $n$th term basically looks like $\dfrac1{e(n-1)}$, which is not summable. I don't have the right argument for you, yet, however.

Comment: This problem is driving me nuts.

Comment: @Edwin (new name, eh?): Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @TedShifrin (Edwin is my real name, Cryme was a nick name :) ). It was an oral examination of ENS contest.

Comment: My only two ideas at the moment: split up the sum with bounds dependent on $x$ (most promising idea to me at the present) or find some clever way to rewrite the sum as an integral which allows for easy manipulations.

Comment: Well, I've also thought about using Holder's inequality in some clever way.

Comment: École Normale Supérieure, @Edwin? Very cool. Une question bien française, il me semble ... :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks :). Oui les oraux des ENS sont d'une difficulté redoutable (pour moi)! C'est un plaisir de savoir que vous parlez français.

Comment: This was an oral exam? How were you supposed to answer this immediatly, when no one here has a solution after two days? I just...no...

Comment: @chubakueno Often the candidate is not supposed to solve the problem completely, the goal of the exam is to assess his reactions to very hard problems. I got a very good grade at my oral exam without succeeding to solve the problem

Comment: There should be a tag "oral-ens" :-)

Comment: Well, @Edwin, now that we see a solution, we see that the problem was "d'une difficulté redoutable" pour tous!! Even my analyst colleagues were stumped. N'ayez pas honte!!

Comment: @TedShifrin Clearly..You are right, thanks for the valuable comment!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem has already been asked in the American Mathematical Monthly (number of the problem 10840 in the volume 107, number 7, December 2000, page 950) and a solution can be found in the volume 109, number 4 (April 2002), pages 398-399 of the American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: You're right the answer is there but I don't know if this count as an answer.

Comment: If this doesn't count as an answer, moderators will probably change this into a comment.

Comment: Well anyway thanks, it's really a tricky question

Comment: Sure it counts as an answer.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to give away jstor content... Many universities have an access, and for the rest of us, there is a (rather) cheap subscription. See *[Terms and Conditions of Use](http://www.jstor.org/page/info/about/policies/terms.jsp)*.

Comment: Thank you, in fact I can read it online here http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2695518?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104157399803.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut jstor allows unaffiliated and unsunbscribing individuals to acess a small number of articles per month, if I recal correctly.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I did quite a basic mistake in the determination of the nth term... Sorry for the answer, which is quite wrong... I put a stop where it is completely off the mark.

Good question, quite interesting. 
Sorry for the non-LateX writing, but I did not write math LateX since a very long time.

The uniform convergence can be proven with the Cauchy criterion.

In that case, since all terms are positive, the criterion can be reduced to $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{(1+x^k)^k}$ and show that $\forall \epsilon$ chosen, there can be a N for which, $\forall x$ between 0 and 1, this Sum is < $\epsilon$.

Basically, we are reduced to study the function $F_{k}(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^k}$...
To study the derivative is to study the function $G_{k}(x)=x^k-kx+1$.
This is fairly easy to show that: for each k>2 there is a 0 for G between 0 and 1 (we note $a_{k}$).

EDIT: This is wrong from now on.
We can show that $a_{k}$ ~ $1/k$ for k big enough.

Each term $F_{k}(a_{k})$ ~ $1/k$ as well, for k big enough. Hence, for N big enough, every $F_{k}(x) < 1/2$.

It is straightforward to then see that the Sum of all the terms can be found < $\epsilon$, $\forall x$... Since $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}$ is bigger than the initial sum and can be found as small as we want.

If someone could format it better in math formulas, that would be great... I will try it in the meanwhile.

Comment: You should have read the very first comment to the OP, by Ted Shifrin. It destroys most of your answer (who should be only a comment in my view)

Comment: Perhaps you mean $G_k(x)=x^k-kx^{\boldsymbol k}+1$ instead.